# Reducer always returning initial state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have been playing with react-native and redux and I have encountered an error. The state is always initialised as the starting one although the payload is present when I debug it inside the reducer.

This is my reducer file

```
let initialState = {
filterList: [],
isFetching: false,
activeFilters: [],
}


export function fetchFilterList(state = initialState, action) {
    return { ...state, isFetching: true };
}

export function fetchFilterListSuccess(state, action) {
    return {
        ...state,
        filterList: action.payload,
        isFetching: true,
        dsad: "dada",
    }
}

export function fetchFilterListError(state, action) {
    return { ...state, isFetching: false };

}
```

This is where I combine them into one function(in the same file as above):

```
export function combinedFiltersReducers(state = initialState, action) {
switch (action.type) {
    case ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_FILTER_LIST:
        return fetchFilterList(state, action);

    case ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_FILTER_LIST_SUCCESS:
        return fetchFilterListSuccess(state, action);

    case ACTION_TYPES.TOGGLE_FILTER_ITEM:
        return toggleFilterItemStart(state, action);

    case ACTION_TYPES.TOGGLE_FILTER_ITEM_SUCCESS:
        return toggleFilterItemSuccess(state, action);

    default:
        return state;
}
```

}

This is my combine reducers function in a separate file called main reducers.

```
    export default combineReducers({
    adList: fetchAdListSuccess,
    filterList: combinedFiltersReducers,
});
```

Here is the where I receive the state in the component, and it always falls to the initial state.

```
    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    filterList: state.filterList,
});

const mapPropsToDispatch = dispatch => ({
    fetchFilterList:() => dispatch(fetchFilterList()),
    toggleFilterItem: (data) => dispatch(toggleFilterItem(data)),
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapPropsToDispatch
)(FilterComponent);
```

I can not find the error, so I need a bit of help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: couldn't find any issue. where you logging the information?

Comment: try adding the logging middleware to redux to get insight into what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I have found an issue. Taking an example:

```
return fetchFilterList(state, action);
```

You're calling `fetchFilterList` method and passing initial state. So every time you call it actually passes the initial state. And that method is just copying the initial state. Rather do like this:

```
return fetchFilterList(...state, action);
```

Comment: But that does the same thing, no? I am later spreading the object inside the functions, which i suppose is the same thing? Or am i wrong here?

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? Later you're copying just initial value not the updated state value.

Comment: I did but it is the same, it has not helped me :(

Comment: @streletss inside the function

Comment: @Tokikko Then, I can strongly say Ross answer is to consider which I felt as a comment though.

Comment: In the end i restarted everything and now it seems to work? I have no idea why or what but after restarting the packager everything seems to be working okay.

Comment: @Tokikko with my suggestion or without? I'm asking it because, I would surprise to see it working perfectly without my suggestion.

Comment: without... i have not changed anything at all, so i am not sure what happened.

Comment: this surprised me either.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that your ACTION_TYPES do not have the appropriate type(s) for the function you are calling so it is reverting to the default case.

Comment: Don't assume. You can comment.

Comment: I can't comment...yet. Your answer, I believe, may be wrong. It is not setting the initialState each time but rather if a state is not defined, it reverts to the initialState.

Comment: I can understand.

Comment: In the end i restarted everything and now it seems to work? I have no idea why or what but after restarting the packager everything seems to be working okay.